# How is dynamic strict applied in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.3.3.

I have the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {
  "entries": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "Data": {
        "properties": {
          "Age": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "BirthDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "Cash": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "Cheque": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "Comments": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "CreditCard": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "FirstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "Gender": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "LastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      "MetaInfo": {
        "properties": {
          "CreatedDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "FormId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "FormName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "FormVersion": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I have put `"dynamic" : "strict"` at the root.

Do I have to specify "dynamic":"strict" to all levels of embedded objects ? In other words, if I set "dynamic":"strict" at the root level then does it apply to embedded objects as well ?

Documentation is not clear about this.

Comment: This is something you can easily test by trying to add a field not in the schema at any level and seeing the result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Elasticsearch "Definitive Guide" says when [talking about dynamic mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html) that:

> The dynamic setting may be applied to the root object or to any field of type object. You could set dynamic to strict by default, but enable it just for a specific inner object...

Which isn't clear about inheritance of this value.  So let's try all options in Elasticsearch 2.4.0 (current version) and see what happens:

#### Options for restricting dynamic mappings:

**1.  Globally**

Set property `index.mapper.dynamic: false` in file `elasticsearch.yml` and it will apply to **all indexes in the system**, such as:

```
index.mapper.dynamic: false
```

Therefore when creating and using an index:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test
  {"acknowledged":true}
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[test] missing","index":"test"}],"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[test] missing","index":"test","caused_by":    {"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled"}},"status":404}
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo": {"bar": 123}}'
  ...same error
```

So for any level of object, root or nested this error shows up.  *Note that the values for this setting are `true`/`false` and not `strict` (which would be ignored as an invalid value).*

**2.  Per Index Setting**

You can do the same setting applied to one specific index, just add `index.mapper.dynamic: false` to the index settings at index creation time and it will apply to all types, and all nesting levels of your objects in that index (and this covers your case nicely).

For example, when creating the index:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
      "index.mapper.dynamic": false}
  }'
  {"acknowledged":true}
```

Then you have an error when using if the field does not exist in the mappings:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[test] missing","index":"test"}],"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[test] missing","index":"test","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled"}},"status":404} 
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo": {"bar": 123}}'
  ...same error
```

So for any level of object, root or nested this error shows up.  *Note that the values for this setting are `true`/`false` and not `strict`.*

**3.  Default For Type Mapping Within One Index**

If you add `"dynamic": "strict"` to the `_default_` type mappings to apply to all types created later:

When creating the index:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
           "dynamic": "strict"
        }
    } 
}'
  {"acknowledged":true}
```

Will give you a slightly new error when trying to add a new unmapped field:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [foo] within [test] is not allowed"}],"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [foo] within [test] is not allowed"},"status":400}
```

Doing the same but adding some fields to a type:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "mappings": {
       "_default_": {
          "dynamic": "strict"
       },
       "test": {
           "properties": {
               "foo": { "type": "string" },
               "bar": { 
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                         "bell": { "type": "string" }
                      }
               }
           }
       }
     }
   }'
```

When trying different attempts, results in:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"foo": "asb"}'
   {"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"bar": { "bell": "abc" } }'
   {"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":2,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":false}
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"bar": { "dog": "abc" } }'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [bar] is not allowed"}],"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [bar] is not allowed"},"status":400}
```

So all levels are strict, including the nested object!

**4.  Within an Object of Index Mappings**

This is what you were directly asking about above, and looks like:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "bar": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "bell": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And when trying to add a non-existing field at the nested level:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"bar": { "dog": "abc" } }'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [bar] is not allowed"}],"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [bar] is not allowed"},"status":400}
```

So there again the strict setting is inherited into nested objects.  If you want, you can override the setting at a nested level to change its meaning from that point downward:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "bar": {
          "type": "nested",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "bell": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And results in:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"bar": { "dog": "abc" } }'
  {"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}
```

But still fails at top level to allow dynamic new fields:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/test/1 -d '{"dog": "abc" }'
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [test] is not allowed"}],"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dog] within [test] is not allowed"},"status":400}
```

### Summary

The quickest answer is that **all** ways you can disable dynamic mappings propagate downwards to all levels of nesting.  You will find old bug reports, old forum messages and other examples that say or imply the opposite but as-of Elasticsearch 2.4.0 (which I used for this testing) the above holds true.

Comment: is there a way to set and unset dynamic mapping globally using REST instead of changing it in elasticsearch.yml ? I am using ElasticSearch 5.3

Comment: That would be a new SO question, or you can search the internet for the API that sets cluster settings, such as https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/cluster-update-settings.html